# Wordpress Custom Fields Integration into Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Okay I'm working with the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin to create custom fields for various categories. I have searched the web for hours on a solution to actually integrate them into the template php to appear. I'm applying it to a page called `archive-product.php` and pulling from a custom field based on the current category.

This is the code i'm using to pull a Custom Field named `slide_title_1`

`<?php the_field("slide_title_1", $category_id); ?>`

Do I need to add code or a variable somewhere else to get this to work?

Any help is SO GREATLY appreciated. Thank you in advance,

Comment: Where is `$category_id` defined? Are you using actual post categories attached to a custom post type called `product` or a custom taxonomy or some other setup? Is this code in the Loop? Is `archive-product.php` a typical archive template or some other custom page template? Post some more detailed context (e.g. custom post types/taxonomies clarification) as well as more code so we can tell more about how you are trying to do this or this will be very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you so much. I'm outside of the loop because I'm working in the Woocommerce archive-product.php template. I've added a custom field to a "Product Category". I'm now trying to call that custom field "slide_title_1". However I want it to be generic to every category... if that makes sense. I want each category page to pull that particular categories' slide_title_1 custom field..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this isn't working because you haven't defined $category_id.

Do the following:

```
<?php
// Your code is in an archive template file so make sure a category is shown.
if ( is_product_category() ) {
    // Get the category ID.
    $category_id = get_query_var( 'product_cat' );

    // Output the custom field.
    the_field( 'slide_title_1', 'product_cat_' . $category_id );
} ?>
```

Also the template file will be for a custom post type named 'product'. Are you aware of the difference between the built-in categories and a custom taxonomy?

UPDATE: Since you're using a WooCommerce product category I've updated the code.

Comment: Looks like he is using the woocommerce product category custom taxonomy not the default category taxonomy, but if this code is updated accordingly I bet it will solve his problem.

Comment: Okay I tried that, but that still seemed not to show any result. I really can't wrap my mind around why. Logically everything seems that it would work.

Comment: And interestingly enough in the code further down on that archive page, I can call this and it does pull the description <p><?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?> </p>

Comment: Actually, Ennui thank you, I just saw your comment. How would I go about updating Nathan's code to reflect WooCommerce custom taxonomy? Is it an obvious fix? (Forgive me, I'm relatively new to extensive woocommerce alterations too)

Comment: `<?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>` may work but that's because the ID is optional. If a valid ID were required it would fail.  Also in the ACF documentation it tells you how to show these values on a category. The code you're using is for a post.